# Is the use of the word "evangelists" correct in the following context?

Tags: word-usage

> Does [name of a religion] tell us to be evangelists?

Or, is the following more appropriate:

> Does [name of a religion] promote evangelism?

Comment: It is hard to tell if a sentence is "formed correctly" when we have no idea what you are trying to say. There are correct sentences that make no sense, and sensible sentences that aren't formed "correctly." Plus, it's harder when you use something like ‘X’ to conceal your intended meaning even further. I would suggesting reading through our [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) meta post, and use that information to improve future questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to say whether it's used correctly since you have given us almost no context. As it stands, overall the sentence is fine, but you do have a small grammar problem in there. Here's how your sentence should look (though, I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to say with it):

> Does X tell us to be evangelists?